# jquery - deselect all selected options in jquery multiselect plugin on change function

Tags: jquery, plugins, multi-select

I'm using [jquery multiselect plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multi-Select-List-with-Checkboxes-MultiSelect.html) 
(you can check demo on [this page](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multi-Select-List-with-Checkboxes-MultiSelect/))

I use two multiselect dropdowns with this plugin

**Explanation below:**
I have two checkboxes on the form, depending on which one is checked, different multiselect dropdown is visible.

The issue here is that selection in the other dropdown is retained and passed to an array.

**What I need:**
whenever one multiselect dropdown becomes visible, I want all selected options in other drop to be unselected/unchecked. So basically make an deselect all on change function.

I tried various selections in jquery below, but I was unsuccessful:

```
$('select[multiple]').multiselect("uncheckAll");
$('#basic option:selected').prop("selected", false);
$('li').removeAttr("selected");
$("#basic option:selected").prop("selected", false);
$("#basic").multiselect('refresh');
$("#basic option[value]").remove();
$('#basic option').removeAttr("selected"); 
$(':checked').removeAttr("selected");
$('#basic').find('li:not(.ms-hidden).selected').removeClass('selected');
$('#basic').find('li:not(.ms-hidden, .selected) 
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled)').prop( 'checked', false );
$('#basic :selected').each(function(){ 
alert($("input[type=checkbox]").val()); 
});
```

As well tried following "jquery.multiselect.js" and changing html elements to make right selectors but with no luck.

I would really appreciate if anybody could help me out.

ps. i tried all proposed solutions from similar topics but none worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try.. its work

```
$('#fillSubject option:selected').prop("selected", false); 
$('select[multiple]').multiselect( 'reload' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".checkbox").on("click",function() { 
  var chk1Checked = $("#checkbox1").is(":checked"),
      chk2Checked = $("#checkbox2").is(":checked");
  $('#select1').multiselect( 'disable', chk2Checked);
  $('#select1').parent().toggle(chk1Checked);  
  $('#select2').multiselect( 'disable', chk1Checked);  
  $('#select2').parent().toggle(chk2Checked);  
});
```